# Recurrent deletion of Resource Groups in an Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager

What would be the best scenario to cleanup a (test) Azure Subscription on weekly basis? Deletion of Resource Groups entirely.

Could be DevOPS, LogicApps, PowerShell, other?

Is there an example out there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requirement, you can [create an automation account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-quickstart-create-account) in your azure. Then create a runbook and use the powershell like below to delete the resource groups:

```
$username = "{client id}"
$password = "{client secret}"
$secureStringPwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $secureStringPwd

Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant '{tenant id}' -ServicePrincipal

$resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup

Foreach($group in $resourceGroups)
{
    Remove-AzResourceGroup $group.ResourceGroupName -Force
}
```

For the parameters `{client id}, {client secret}, {tenant id}` in above code, you need to [register an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-an-application) in your AD. You can find the `client id` and `tenant id` in the "Overview" page of your registered application.

[image]

Then click "**Certificates & secret**" and "New client secret".

[image]

Then you can put the three parameters into your powershell code in runbook.

Before use the registered application(service principal) to connect to azure and do remove resource groups operation, you need to assign permission to this service principal. Copy the name of your registered application and go to your "Subscription" and click "Access control(IAM)", then add role assignment.

[image]

Then you need to assign at least "Contributor" role to the service principal.

[image]

After that, you need to import modules of az command in your automation account and then you can run the powershell runbook.

To schedule the runbook, you can click "Schedules" --> "Add schedule" in your runbook to add a schedule which you want.

[image]

[image]

=============================**Update**===========================

For your further requirement, you can create a policy first.

[image]

In policy edit page, you can define the policy like below:

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
        },
        {
          "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
          "exists": "false"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "modify",
      "details": {
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
        ],
        "operations": [
          {
            "operation": "add",
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
            "value": "[utcNow()]"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "tagName": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Name",
        "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
      },
      "defaultValue": "CreatedTime"
    }
  }
}
```

Then [assign the policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/assign-policy-portal#create-a-policy-assignment) to your subscription. After that, when create a resource group, it will generate a `CreatedTime` tag.

[image]

Then you need to modify your powershell, check if the resource group createdTime older than a value which you want. Please refer to the script below, I test it in my side with remove resource group which created longer than 48 hours.

```
$resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup
$TimeOutHours=48

foreach($group in $resourceGroups)
{
    $Tags = $group.Tags

    if ($Tags -ne $null)
    {
         
        if ($Tags.ContainsKey("CreatedTime"))
        {
            $CreatedTimeInTags = $Tags['CreatedTime']
            $CreatedTime=New-Object DateTime

            if (![DateTime]::TryParse($CreatedTimeInTags,[ref] $CreatedTime))
            {
                if (![Datetime]::TryParseExact($CreatedTimeInTags, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ',$null,$null,[ref] $CreatedTime))
                {
                    if(![Datetime]::TryParseExact($CreatedTimeInTags, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss',$null,$null, [ref]$CreatedTime))
                    {
                            Write-Output "Failed to recognize the datetime for $($group.ResourceGroupName). Skip it."
                            continue 
                    }
                }
            }

            if( $CreatedTime.Year -ne 1)
            {
                $hoursDiff=((get-date).ToUniversalTime() - $CreatedTime).TotalHours

                if($hoursDiff -ge $TimeOutHours)
                {
                    Write-Output "Removing resource:$($group.ResourceGroupName)"
                    Remove-AzResourceGroup $group.ResourceGroupName -Force
                }
            }
           
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!   What if I want to delete RGs older than 1 week from a certain Subscription?

Comment: Hi @DanielSotreanu I will do some test and provide you solution tomorrow.

Comment: @DanielSotreanu Please refer to the update of my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hury Shen! You're the best!